# SQL Last 12 months sum

Tags: sql

Need sql help from the below data .
`ExpectedResult` is the column I would like to derive .

```
MonthBeginDate  cnt ExpectedResult
1/12/2019   51  0
1/01/2020   161 0
1/02/2020   243 0
1/03/2020   252 0
1/04/2020   214 0
1/05/2020   309 0
1/06/2020   309 0
1/07/2020   324 0
1/08/2020   363 0
1/09/2020   311 0
1/10/2020   373 0
1/11/2020   260 0
1/12/2020   249 3419
1/01/2021   205 3573
1/02/2021   255 3667
1/03/2021   217 3641
1/04/2021   165 3554
1/05/2021   158 3498
1/06/2021   158 3347
1/07/2021   237 3275
1/08/2021   319 3270
1/09/2021   227 3134
1/10/2021   297 3120
1/11/2021   16  2763
```

Comment: How is ExpectedResult calculated?  It doesn’t seem to be a simple sum.   Eg 3667-3573 = 94, but there doesn’t seem to be any cnt numbers with a difference of 94 a year previously.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Column MonthBeginDate data type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with window functions. Nowadays only very few SQL database management systems do not support window functions - or OLAP functions, or analytic functions, as they are also called. Those that have an `OVER()` clause.

I now count the rows between the current row and the beginning of the range - `COUNT(*)` - and only if this value is > 12 do I calculate the running sum: `SUM(cnt)`. And in both cases the `OVER()` clause is: `OVER(ORDER BY monthbegindate ROWS BETWEEN 12 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)` .

See here how it works:

```
WITH                                                                                                                                                                                                
-- your input ...
indata(MonthBeginDate,cnt,ExpectedResult) AS (
          SELECT DATE '1/12/2019',51,0
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '1/01/2020',161,0
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '1/02/2020',243,0
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '1/03/2020',252,0
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '1/04/2020',214,0
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '1/05/2020',309,0
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '1/06/2020',309,0
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '1/07/2020',324,0
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '1/08/2020',363,0
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '1/09/2020',311,0
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '1/10/2020',373,0
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '1/11/2020',260,0
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '1/12/2020',249,3419
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '1/01/2021',205,3573
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '1/02/2021',255,3667
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '1/03/2021',217,3641
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '1/04/2021',165,3554
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '1/05/2021',158,3498
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '1/06/2021',158,3347
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '1/07/2021',237,3275
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '1/08/2021',319,3270
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '1/09/2021',227,3134
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '1/10/2021',297,3120
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '1/11/2021',16,2763
)
-- real query starts here ...
SELECT 
  * 
, CASE 
    WHEN COUNT(*) OVER(
      ORDER BY monthbegindate 
      ROWS BETWEEN 12 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
     ) > 12
    THEN SUM(cnt) OVER(
      ORDER BY monthbegindate 
      ROWS BETWEEN 12 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
     ) 
    ELSE 0
  END AS calcres
FROM indata;
```

And the result table:

```
MonthBeginDate | cnt | ExpectedResult | calcres 
---------------+-----+----------------+---------
2019-01-12     |  51 |              0 |       0
2020-01-01     | 161 |              0 |       0
2020-01-02     | 243 |              0 |       0
2020-01-03     | 252 |              0 |       0
2020-01-04     | 214 |              0 |       0
2020-01-05     | 309 |              0 |       0
2020-01-06     | 309 |              0 |       0
2020-01-07     | 324 |              0 |       0
2020-01-08     | 363 |              0 |       0
2020-01-09     | 311 |              0 |       0
2020-01-10     | 373 |              0 |       0
2020-01-11     | 260 |              0 |       0
2020-01-12     | 249 |           3419 |    3419
2021-01-01     | 205 |           3573 |    3573
2021-01-02     | 255 |           3667 |    3667
2021-01-03     | 217 |           3641 |    3641
2021-01-04     | 165 |           3554 |    3554
2021-01-05     | 158 |           3498 |    3498
2021-01-06     | 158 |           3347 |    3347
2021-01-07     | 237 |           3275 |    3275
2021-01-08     | 319 |           3270 |    3270
2021-01-09     | 227 |           3134 |    3134
2021-01-10     | 297 |           3120 |    3120
2021-01-11     |  16 |           2763 |    2763
```